# Not able to doubleClick Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in Automation Testing. I have installed Eclipse as an IDE for performing Automation Task and the language I am using is Java. I have a module in my web-app in which I need to perform double click on a web element very fast. The time difference between the first and second clicks should be less than half a second.

I have written the following code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sonam')]"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the mouse to element first.

Try this

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sonam')]"))).doubleClick().perform();
```

or just:

```
 action.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sonam')]"))).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Actions class you can able to do DoubleClick on element.

Here you go:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sonam')]"))).build().perform();
```

OR

You can use JavaScriptExecutor to doubleClick using Javascript as below:

```
String jsCodeToDblClick = "var targElement=arguments[0]; var clEvent=document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); clEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true');targElement.dispatchEvent (clEvent);";

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(jsCodeToDblClick ,driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sonam')]")));
```

This works!!!

Comment: String jsCodeToDblClick = "var targElement=arguments[0]; var"
                   clEvent=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');                                              Following error is coming in code:                                                                     For First line : Multiple markers at this line                                                      For Second line : Invalid Character Constant

Comment: Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: @smishra0105 sure. can you show the exact execption/error? 
And consider whatever string in jsCodeDblClick as a single line. And yes please share code snippet you are trying.

Comment: All the exceptions i fixed. Yet the double click is not possible on it. Guide me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:-

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sonam')]")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(ele1).build().perform();
```